# How to achieve thread safety with a timed Windows Forms update?

Tags: c#

In my C# program I'm trying to get a Panel to call OnPaint() once a second to do some Graphics drawing based on current settings. The main form uses a System.Timers.Timer to call the Panel class' update method, which ends with a Refresh() call. But when I run it, I always get an InvalidOperationExcetpion that refers to the Refresh line and says "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." It also refers me to this MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

But all the examples on that page seem to suggest tying a new thread to a specific form event. I'm updating based on a timer, not a mouse click or similar event. Running the refresh on a separate thread sounds good to me, but I'm not sure how I'd do it (I'm good with Java, but a C# newbie).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The main form uses a System.Timers.Timer to call the Panel class' update method

Two options:

- Set [`Timer.SynchronizationObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx) to the panel, so it will fire the ticks in the UI thread
- Use [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) in the first place, which will always raise the tick even in the UI thread

Basically, you shouldn't access UI elements from a different thread - you can marshal to the right thread via `Control.Invoke` or `Control.BeginInvoke`, but if you don't have any significant work to do *other* than updating the UI, you might as well just force the timer to raise the event in the UI thread.

Comment: Switching to the System.Windows.Forms Timer did the trick. Thank you.